# Use different framework for another framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, opencv

In my app I want to use [Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com/) and [Openalpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr). I try to integrate both of them as frameworks in my XCode Project. The problem is that if I integrate OpenCV.framework (It is required by Openalpr) I get the following error when initializing Openalpr:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7564
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7564: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

I think that Wikitude is also using openCV (should be included in the framework already) and I assume it uses a different version of it and Openalpr is not compatible with the version of OpenCV which Wikitude requires. So maybe there is a conflict between these two frameworks and their usage of OpenCV.framework

**My question is: Is there a way to import the OpenCV.framework so that only Openalpr.framework can use it and Wikitude.framework still uses it´s version of OpenCV?**

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this problem out? I have a similar one. Thanks!

Comment: @micamoita: Unfortunately we never found a solution for the problem. We ended up using a different library. One solution would also be to ask one of the framework providers for a version using a different version of a sub-framework. I hope you find a solution for your project!